# Is “happy time” spoken English?

Tags: spoken-english

> So – and here comes the question – why is there not as much happiness
> as there is happy time gone by?

Happy time means the time when someone is happy, but it doesn’t mean the time which feels happy. I doubt this expression is spoken English, isn’t it?

Comment: The sentence is strange. Where did you find it? No, it is not correct that you will find "happy time" in only spoken English. It is a common expression.

Comment: "He would lie awake until the early hours of the morning weaving his fantasies. It was a lonely and curiously happy time. " - from "The Fourth K" by Mario Puzo

Comment: @Man_From_India Book named “The Quest for the Good Life: Ancient Philosophers on Happiness”

Comment: The "gone by" part throws me.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to refer to 'happy _times_ gone by' - past occasions when you were happy.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it was written by a native speaker, honestly. More context would be helpful. "Happy time" does occur in AmE, but it's not common.